# Django session unexpectedly loses data

Tags: python, django, session, django-settings

I have an admin action which stores the current selection and a handler class (subclass of `object`) to the session, and redirects to another page which processes the selection.  For some reason however, whenever I do this, the entire session is lost.

What actually happens is that I get an error during calling the view function that session has no key 'action_options'.  Digging into what actually happens, the variables get set in the session fine, but by the time the view is called, the session is completely empty, including admin logins which were definitely there before.  All other pages (i.e. builtin admin pages) load fine.

Here's the action:

```
def myaction(self, request, queryset):
    opts = request.session.setdefault('action_options', {})
    opts['queryset'] = queryset
    opts['handler'] = MyHandlerClass
    request.session.modified = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp.views.handler_view'))
```

And here's the view, which currently just prints out the options set:

```
def handler_view(request):
    opts = request.session['action_options']
    return HttpResponse(str(opts))
```

I have also tried storing the queryset directly, i.e. `request.session['queryset'] = queryset`, but I get the same behaviour.  However, if I save a list of primary keys, its fine.

For reference, here's my middleware definition:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    'johnny.middleware.LocalStoreClearMiddleware',
    'johnny.middleware.QueryCacheMiddleware',
)
```

I am using Johnny Cache, with the following configuration:

```
CACHES = {
    'default' : dict(
        BACKEND='johnny.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        LOCATION=['127.0.0.1:11211'],
        JOHNNY_CACHE=True,
    )
}
JOHNNY_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = 'jc_myproj'
```

Answer (score 0):

Queryset, before it is executed, can not be serialized and stored in session.

```
opts['queryset'] = list(queryset)
```

This would make it a list, but still the question is whether it can be serialized and deserialized. Basicaly, session data is plain text. Plan accordingly.